# Does the server-side script need to be defined in "routes"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm working one a NodeJS Express app and as far as I can understand, server-client communication works by putting an AJAX script into a Javascript file (that's the client side) and putting a listener function ( `function(req, res){}` basically ) into another one. (that's the server side)

Tell me if it's wrong. Otherwise, I have a question regarding it: on client-side there's is a Jade file with the aforementioned AJAX script attached with `script include`. To make this site work on a very basic level, I made the next script in the **/routes** folder (and had to define some variables in app.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('name-of-the-Jade-file', { title: 'Site title' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Do I have to make a similar script to the same folder for the listener function too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-Client communication, in the context of the WWW, works by making HTTP requests and receiving HTTP responses. (At least unless you want to get into using things like Web Sockets).

Ajax is the name given to "Making an HTTP request and handling its response with client side JavaScript". You could also use a plain HTML link or form submission to communicate with the server from a webpage.

Routes are just a common design pattern used, on the server, to examine the URL that the client requested and run the appropriate code to respond to it. Express uses them.

---

If you want to use Ajax then you need some code on the client that uses XMLHttpRequest (or JSONP or iframe hacks) to make the HTTP request to the server.

Then you need to write some code to respond to it. `render` is the method that Express uses to take some data, format it, and then send it in a response back to the client. There may be other methods provided by Express that serve the same purpose, but you'll usually need to use `render`.

Comment: So if I want to make calculations or other variable modifications and sent that back to client, then I have to put all that code into the file in *routes*, or can I use `render` even outside?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt — As I said, in Express (which you are using), a route is how you determine which function to call. If you don't make it a route, how is the function going to get called at all?

Comment: Question: I realized `render` always needs an input it can render, but local vars can be defined too. Does it mean that with AJAX, I can modify variable which are declared in the calling of `render`?

Comment: You can't declare variables in the middle of a call to a function, so I'm not sure what you mean. `render`, AFAIK, needs to know what it is that you want to put in the HTTP response. The client side JS that processes that response can do whatever it likes with the data.

Comment: I mean that e.g. in case of `res.render('index', { name: "Quentin"} )`, AJAX can be used to modify only `name` and no other variables. Is that right?

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. Ajax, as I mentioned previously, just means making an HTTP request. You can do whatever you like with your data on the server. Then you send some data to the client. The client can then do whatever it likes with the data that it has received. That can't affect anything on the server because the request has finished.

Comment: Oops, yes, I fixed that, sorry. I guess I was confused with the methods of sending and requesting data and that caused some misunderstanding.